# quit while loop whilst iterating through SQL table

Tags: java, sql

I want to add items from a SQL table to an Java ArrayList.  To get each item in the table, I am using the loop:

```
while(results.next())
```

However, I believe that this won't quit the loop if there are no more results found unlike the `.hasNext` available from some classes and will cause an error of some sort. How would I get the while loop to quit if there is nothing else in the SQL table without causing an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Looking at the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29), i think it should work fine. Snippet from the docs:

```
Returns:
    true if the new current row is valid; false if there are no more rows
```

I hope you are talking about ResultSet

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using a [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), this is straight from the JavaDocs:

> The next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.